# what does the field docs.deleted mean in elasticsearch _cat/indices API response?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is the index statistics.

```
Avinashs-MacBook-Pro:~ avinashpandey$ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

health status index            pri rep docs.count **docs.deleted** store.size pri.store.size 

yellow open   sitemonitor-5min   5   1    8151707       **221036**      1.2gb          1.2gb
```

I am sure I have only been doing HTTP Post at /index/type/_id and have not deleted a single document. Where do these deleted docs come from then?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A overwrite ( An index operation on existing document ) or an update operation also does delete in background.

Due to immutability  of segments in Lucene index , deletion operation is not exactly possible easily. For any change to the original document operation , like reindex or update , it needs to delete the document , mark it as deleted and create a new document with the change , in the background.

You are seeing this delete because you might have used UPDATE API or written a document to a doc ID which already exist.

Comment: I have updated my document , but deletion count has not increased , are you sure ?

Comment: The number of documents deleted we see in our ES *decreases* over time ... weird, please advise.

Comment: When the merge happens ( This happens occasionally ) , the deleted documents are actually removed. This is when you see a decrease.

Comment: can we delete the docs from **docs.deleted**?